# How can I store floating point values in Meteor (JS) using Collections2?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I have a Number data type in the schema (simple-schema) but am unable to store floating point numbers in it when using collections2:

`Schema.Coordinates = new SimpleSchema({
    lng: {
        type: Number,
        min: -180.0,
        max: 180.0
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        min: -90.0,
        max: 90.0
    }
});`

When I try to insert anything other than an integer (anything with xxxx.0) I get a validation error:

`W20150222-20:24:23.523(-8)? (STDERR) Error: Lng must be an integer`

Answer (score 4):

As has already been stated, setting `decimal` to true will allow for floating point numbers.

I just wanted to make another suggestion. Since you're trying to store log/lat this would be a better schema:

```
loc:
   type: Object
   index: '2dsphere'
   label: "Location"

"loc.type": 
   type: String
   allowedValues: [ "Point" ]
   label: "Start location type"

"loc.coordinates":
   type: [Number]
   minCount: 2
   maxCount: 2
   decimal: true
```

That allows you to store the coordinates in [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) format so that you can then use Mongo's spacial operators (such as [$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)) on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `decimal` to true ([docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#decimal)). I guess this is a bit like *optional* else like the other answer.

```
Schema.Coordinates = new SimpleSchema({
    lng: {
        type: Number,
        min: -180.0,
        max: 180.0,
        decimal:true,
    },
    lat: {
        type: Number,
        min: -90.0,
        max: 90.0,
        decimal: true,
    }
});
```